# Close or discard MFC dialog after a given period of time

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

how to close or discard a MFC dialog box  Automatically after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 12):

Declare an ID for your timer, i.e. in your `CMyDialog.h` somewhere:

```
static const UINT ID_MY_TIMER = 1000;
```

Create a timer in your `OnInitDialog` function:

```
SetTimer(ID_MY_TIMER, 10000, NULL); // 10000ms = 10 secs
```

Add a handler for `WM_TIMER` (the generated function will be called `OnTimer`):

```
void CMyDialog::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if (nIDEvent == ID_MY_TIMER)
    {
        EndDialog(IDOK);
    }
    ...
}
```

Replace `IDOK` with `IDCANCEL` depending on what you return result you want from DoModal.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906.aspx) with 10 seconds timeout. On the timer message handler post close message.