# Custom message box that automatically disappears

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I need to add to an existing MFC app, a customize message box that will disappear after few seconds if the user didn't press 'OK'.

How to do that?

I'm basic familiar with MFC but well with c++.

Comment: Use a Modeless dialog.

Comment: As @seccpur says just adding have the Modeless dialog post itself a WM_TImer message, on receive it can close itself.

Comment: You don't need a modeless dialog to set up a timer, whose handler closes the dialog. This approach works with *any* dialog.

Comment: You may find [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/980166/898348) interesting. [This Codeproject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19714/Auto-close-message-box) might be even more interesting if your are specifically interested in an autoclosing standard Windows message box.

Comment: use `MessageBoxTimeoutW`

Comment: @RbMm `MessageBoxTimeoutW` is an undocumented function, therefore IMO it's bad advice using it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - and so what that it undocumented ?

Comment: @RbMm beause undocumented functions may go away in future versions of Windows.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - no any reason for this. can you give me examples (several api names) that go away ? this is extremely rarely.  this concrete api - exist already 20 years (how minimum from win2000), used by `MessageBoxW`, - absolute no any reasons to remove it

Comment: @RbMm even if the likleyhood of `MessageBoxTimeout` being removed in some future release of Windows is low, I wouldn't use it. But of course everybody is free to use it on their own risk.

Comment: @RbMm: This question is tagged [tag:winapi]. Undocumented functions are - by definition - not part of the documented API surface.

Comment: @IInspectable - this is exported function from one of windows dll (user32.dll), like and `MessageBoxW`. no any difference here. what is documented or not - is separate topic.

Comment: @RbMm: I understand, that you are **still** having trouble understanding contracts. The OP requested a solution using the Windows API (or MFC). Undocumented exports are not part of the Windows API. It's unclear to me, what's not to understand about that.

Comment: @IInspectable - *Undocumented exports are not part of the Windows API* - this is you think. i think that export is part of winapi. and what is documented or not - vague concept

Comment: @RbMm: If that is the case, can you link us to official documentation, that backs *your* opinion on what is and isn't part of the API? Or let me ask you another question: Have you *ever* signed a contract? And did you ever get sued for a clause, that wasn't present in that contract?

Comment: @IInspectable - you begin discussion what is part or not of winapi. i based on very simply thing - api is exported functions from built-in windows dlls.

Comment: @RbMm: I understand, that that's *your* understanding. You will not find anyone (including the vendor of the OS) that would agree with you. This question clearly asked for a solution based on the documented API. Proposing to use something that isn't is not applicable. Anyway, I'm wasting my time. You'll understand this, once you become a professional developer. Given your current mindset, that's not going to happen anytime soon.

Comment: @IInspectable *clearly asked for a solution based on the documented API.* not such words "documented" in question. this is you add

Answer (score 6):

This can be done without having to write a custom dialog by using [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialogindirect).

## Basic Steps

1. Set the `TDF_CALLBACK_TIMER` bit in [`TASKDIALOGCONFIG::dwFlags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-_taskdialogconfig). This will invoke a callback (if specified) approximately every 200 ms.
2. Assign a [callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb760542(v=VS.85).aspx) to `TASKDIALOGCONFIG::pfCallback`.
3. When the callback gets called with the [`TDN_TIMER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/tdn-timer) notification code, compare the elapsed time that is passed to the callback via `wParam`, with your desired timeout value. To close the dialog, send it a [`TDM_CLICK_BUTTON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tdm-click-button) message.

You can go fancy and display a progress bar (`TDF_SHOW_PROGRESS_BAR`) or just show a countdown text that you update in the timer callback. See [Task Dialog Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bumper-task-dialogs-reference-messages).

## Example

Here is an example using plain windows API. MFC has the `CTaskDialog` class, but I think this answer will be more useful if it doesn't depend much on MFC. For non-MFC users, only the assignments to `tc.hInstance` and `tc.hwndParent` need to be changed.

```
TASKDIALOGCONFIG tc{ sizeof(tc) };
tc.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
tc.hwndParent = GetSafeHwnd();  // assuming you call this from a dialog member function
tc.dwFlags = TDF_CALLBACK_TIMER | TDF_SIZE_TO_CONTENT;
tc.dwCommonButtons = TDCBF_OK_BUTTON;
tc.pszWindowTitle = L"Task dialog with timeout";
tc.pszContent = L"This dialog will close after 5 seconds!";

DWORD timeout = 5000;  // milliseconds
tc.lpCallbackData = reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>( &timeout );

// Assign a lambda function as callback.
tc.pfCallback = []( HWND hwnd, UINT uNotification, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LONG_PTR dwRefData )
{
    if( uNotification == TDN_TIMER )
    {
        DWORD* pTimeout = reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>( dwRefData );  // = tc.lpCallbackData
        DWORD timeElapsed = static_cast<DWORD>( wParam );
        if( *pTimeout && timeElapsed >= *pTimeout )
        {
            *pTimeout = 0; // Make sure we don't send the button message multiple times.
            SendMessage( hwnd, TDM_CLICK_BUTTON, IDOK, 0 );
        }
    }
    return S_OK;
};

::TaskDialogIndirect( &tc, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr );
```

Comment: why not simply call `MessageBoxTimeoutW` ?

Comment: @RbMm Undocumented and outdated API.

Comment: what you mean under *outdated* ? it exist in all windows versions, how minimum from win2000 until latest win10

Comment: @RbMm As it's undocumented, it can be removed at any time in the future. Outdated, because of Task Dialog API which is more powerful.

Comment: i not not view how more powerful bind with outdate. exist different api for which exist more power version, but this not meant that this api is outdated

Answer (score 5):

the most simplest way, if you want only messagebox with timeout use next undocumented api from user32.dll:

```
extern "C"
WINUSERAPI int WINAPI MessageBoxTimeoutW(IN HWND hWnd, 
                            IN PCWSTR lpText, IN PCWSTR lpCaption, 
                            IN UINT uType, IN WORD wLanguageId, IN DWORD dwMilliseconds);
```

all what we need - add this declaration to *c++* code and link with *user32.lib*, but this we usually do by default. after this call it simply as usual `MessageBoxW` with 2 additional parameters. the last how simply view - the tiemout in miliseconds.

for example:

```
MessageBoxTimeoutW(HWND_DESKTOP, L"Text", 
    L"Caption", MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_YESNO, 0, 4000);
```

note that `MessageBoxW` simply call `MessageBoxTimeoutW` :

```
int MessageBoxW(
  HWND    hWnd,
  LPCTSTR lpText,
  LPCTSTR lpCaption,
  UINT    uType
)
{
    return MessageBoxTimeoutW(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType, 0, INFINITE);
}
```

so first 4 parameters and return value like in `MessageBoxW` api. in case message box closed by timeout - `IDTIMEOUT` returned (declared in *winuser.h* ) except `MB_OK` used (single *OK* button) - in this case always `IDOK` returned.